# Найти в URL часть строки

Tags: javascript

Как проверить есть ли в URL часть строки.
Строка полного вида

```
index.php?route=catalog/product/edit&user_token=BrNypCZLBTKEZLU04b0YatYdMo5YmLRd&product_id=51
```

пытаюсь проверить но как то тщетно, в чем именно у меня ошибка и как это сделать

```
<script>
var path = window.location.search;
if (path.match("/^\?route=catalog/product/edit$/")) alert ("yes")
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`search()` или `indexOf()`. Оба возвращают позицию, с которой начинается искомая подстрока или -1, если подстрока в строке не найдена.

```js
  var path = "index.php?route=catalog/product/edit&user_token=BrNypCZLBTKEZLU04b0YatYdMo5YmLRd&product_id=51"; 
  var n = path.search("route=catalog/product/edit");
  if (n => 0 ) alert ("yes");
```

или

```js
      var path = "index.php?route=catalog/product/edit&user_token=BrNypCZLBTKEZLU04b0YatYdMo5YmLRd&product_id=51";
      var n = path.indexOf("route=catalog/product/edit");
      if (n => 0 ) alert ("yes");
```